# How to change the graphql typedefs name that is coming from json results of external api?

Tags: graphql

I have encountered an issue with the naming in my typedefs. The error prompting the following.

> Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int "24"

I am using [Coinmarketcap Api](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/) and accessing it with my apollo graphql server. The api has naming such as `24h_volume_usd`, `percent_change_1h` etc, but as long as integer within the name, it will have this name issue.

I am not really sure how can I fix this issue. Can anyone please help me out? Thank you very much.

`Schema.js`:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type cryptos {
        id: String
        name: String
        symbol: String
        rank: String
        price_usd: String
        price_btc: String
        24h_volume_usd: String
        market_cap_usd: String
        percent_change_1h: String
        available_supply: String
        total_supply: String
        last_updated: String
    }

    type Query {
        cryptos: [cryptos]
    }
`
```

`resolvers.js`:

```
const resolvers = {
Query: {
    cryptos: () => {
        return axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/').
        then(result => result.data );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process api result using map functions

```
`var newHashmap = {}; 
 Object.keys(hashmap).forEach(function(key){ 
 var value = hashmap[key]; 
 key = key + "xxx"; 
 console.log("changing:"); 
 console.log(key); newHashmap[key] = value 
 });`
```